# Perforce integrating multiple changelists from one branch to another keeping them as separate changelists

Tags: merge, perforce, branching-and-merging

I'm wondering if there's an easy solution to this workflow. I work using the perforce GUI (P4V), but I'm not adverse to using the command line for this. In any case, let's say I fix 3 bugs working on my personal development branch. Each one I submit to my personal devel branch in 3 different change lists.

Now I want to merge/integrate those to the main branch. Currently, when I do that all 3 change lists get squashed into a single one in the main branch. However, is there a simple way to do this so that all 3 changelists remain separated? The only other option I see is to cherry pick change lists -click on each changelist in the history tab,-- and merge them there one by one...

Suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Rodrigo

Answer (score 1):

If you want 3 changelists on the main branch, you have to submit 3 times:

```
p4 integ my_dev/...@A,A main/...
p4 resolve -am
p4 submit -d "merged A to main from my_dev"

p4 integ my_dev/...@B,B main/...
p4 resolve -am
p4 submit -d "merged B to main from my_dev"

p4 integ my_dev/...@C,C main/...
p4 resolve -am
p4 submit -d "merged C to main from my_dev"
```